# FFmpeg C++ Не удается получить корректную информацию об аудиопотоке

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Мне нужно засунуть FFmpeg в мое приложение для воспроизведения видео. По какой-то причине FFmpeg не может получить корректные данные аудиопотока. Вот часть кода которая работает некорректно:

```cpp
if (avformat_open_input(&m_data->formatContext, Filename.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Motion: Failed to open file: '" << Filename << "'" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        if (avformat_find_stream_info(m_data->formatContext, nullptr) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Motion: Failed to find stream information" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_data->formatContext->nb_streams; i++)
        {
            // Получаем параметры кодека для текущего потока
            AVCodecParameters *codecParams = m_data->formatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;

            switch (codecParams->codec_type)
            {

            case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
            if (m_data->audioStreamID == -1 && EnableAudio)
                m_data->audioStreamID = i;
            break;

            default:
            break;
            }
        }

    

        if (HasAudio())
        {
            const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_data->formatContext->streams[m_data->audioStreamID]->codecpar->codec_id);
            std::cout << m_data->formatContext->streams[m_data->audioStreamID]->codecpar->codec_id<< std::endl;
            m_data->audioContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

            if (!m_data->audioContext)
            {
                std::cout << "Motion: Failed to get audio codec context" << std::endl;
                m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                m_data->audioCodec = codec;

                if (!m_data->audioCodec)
                {
                    std::cout << "Motion: Failed to find audio codec" << std::endl;
                    m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (avcodec_open2(m_data->audioContext, m_data->audioCodec, nullptr) != 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Motion: Failed to load audio codec" << std::endl;
                        m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_data->audioRawBuffer = av_frame_alloc();

                        if (!m_data->audioRawBuffer)
                        {
                            std::cout << "Motion: Failed to allocate audio buffer" << std::endl;
                            m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             int buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(nullptr, m_data->audioContext->channels, MAX_AUDIO_SAMPLES, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);
                            if (buffer_size < 0) {
    
                                char err_buf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
                                av_strerror(buffer_size, err_buf, sizeof(err_buf));
                                std::cerr << "Motion: Failed to calculating buffer size: " << err_buf << std::endl;
                                m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
                            }
                            else if (av_samples_alloc(&m_data->audioPCMBuffer, nullptr, m_data->audioContext->channels, av_samples_get_buffer_size(nullptr, m_data->audioContext->channels, MAX_AUDIO_SAMPLES, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0), AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0) < 0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "Motion: Failed to create audio samples buffer" << std::endl;
                                m_data->audioStreamID = -1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                av_frame_unref(m_data->audioRawBuffer);

                                uint64_t inchanlayout = m_data->audioContext->channel_layout;
                                uint64_t outchanlayout = inchanlayout;

                                if (inchanlayout == 0)
                                    inchanlayout = av_get_default_channel_layout(m_data->audioContext->channels);

                                if (outchanlayout != AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO)
                                    outchanlayout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;

                                m_data->audioSWContext = swr_alloc();
                                std::cout << m_data->audioContext->sample_rate << std::endl;
                                std::cout << m_data->audioContext->sample_fmt << std::endl;
                                av_opt_set_int(m_data->audioSWContext, "in_channel_layout", inchanlayout, 0);
                                av_opt_set_int(m_data->audioSWContext, "out_channel_layout", outchanlayout, 0);
                                av_opt_set_int(m_data->audioSWContext, "in_sample_rate", m_data->audioContext->sample_rate, 0);
                                av_opt_set_int(m_data->audioSWContext, "out_sample_rate", m_data->audioContext->sample_rate, 0);
                                av_opt_set_sample_fmt(m_data->audioSWContext, "in_sample_fmt", m_data->audioContext->sample_fmt, 0);
                                av_opt_set_sample_fmt(m_data->audioSWContext, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 0);

                                swr_init(m_data->audioSWContext);

                                m_audioChannelCount = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(outchanlayout);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

В консоли выводит ошибку "Motion: Failed to calculating buffer size: Invalid argument". Эта ошибка возникает из-за того что avcodec_alloc_context3(codec)->channels == 0, но так не должно быть.У видеофайла должен быть второй аудиоканал [image: введите сюда описание изображения]